# Javascript rotate sprite?

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, sprite, angle

So I am working on this game with a friend. And we are having some trouble getting the sprite to rotate. The angle is always -2.356194490192345. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the code below?

> var angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y-MC.drawY, mouse.x-MC.drawX);

```
//Rotating the sprite to face mouse
//Get mouse position
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX; 
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
}, false);

> function DrawMainChar(){
>     ctx.clearRect( 0 , 0 , 800 , 600 );
>     ctx.save();
>     ctx.translate(MC.drawX+8, MC.drawY+8);
>     ctx.rotate(angle);
>     ctx.translate(-MC.drawX+8, -MC.drawY+8);
>     ctx.drawImage(imgSprite, MC.srcX, MC.srcY, MC.width, MC.height, MC.drawX, MC.drawY, MC.width, MC.height);
>     ctx.restore();    //RoundStarter(); 
   }
```

Comment: Start by adding `console.log(mouse.y,MC.drawY,mouse.x,MC.drawX)` where you compute `angle` to check you have the right input values.

Comment: The numbers are all updating like its supposed to however the angle still stays at the same -2.356194490192345

Comment: You log all 4 inputs + angle (all at the same time), and even though the 4 inputs change, the angle computed by `Math.atan2` is always the same?